# Slash after domain in URL missing for Rails site

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails

After redirecting users in a Rails app, for some reason the slash after the domain is missing. Generated URLs are invalid and I'm forced to manually correct them. The problem only occurs on a subdomain. On a different primary domain (same server), everything works ok.

For example, after logging out, the site is directing to **https://www.sub.domain.comlogin/** rather than **https://www.sub.domain.com/login**

I suspect the issue has something to do with the vhost setup, but I'm not sure. Here are the broken and working vhosts:

**BROKEN SUBDOMAIN**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.sub.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.sub.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin email@email.com
  ServerName www.sub.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub.domain.com
  RailsEnv production

  # SSL Engine Switch
  SSLEngine on

  # SSL Cipher Suite:
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

  # Server Certificate
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt

  # Server Private Key
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key

  # Set header to indentify https requests for Mongrel
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
  nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
  downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  DocumentRoot /home/usr/www/www.sub.domain.com/current/public/
  <Directory "/home/usr/www/www.sub.domain.com/current/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

**WORKING PRIMARY DOMAIN**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.diffdomain.com
  ServerAlias diffdomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.diffdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin email@email.com
  ServerName www.diffdomain.com
  ServerAlias diffdomain.com
  ServerAlias *.diffdomain.com
  RailsEnv production

  # SSL Engine Switch
SSLEngine on

  # SSL Cipher Suite:
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

  # Server Certificate
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt

  # Server Private Key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key

  # Set header to indentify https requests for Mongrel
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
  nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
  downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  DocumentRoot /home/usr/www/www.diffdomain.com/current/public/
  <Directory "/home/usr/www/www.diffdomain.com/current/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I could provide that would help determine what's wrong here.

**UPDATE**
tried adding a trailing slash to the redirect command, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked another developer about this and here's how he fixed it:

I made new a vhost file for you. On previous vhost config, there was something wrong on server name and server alias. I removed 'www'. Also I added `config.force_ssl = true` to environments/production.rb

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://sub.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin email@email.com
  ServerName sub.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub.domain.com
  RailsEnv production
  RailsBaseURI /

  # SSL Engine Switch
  SSLEngine on

  # SSL Cipher Suite:
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

  # Server Certificate
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt

  # Server Private Key
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key

  # Set header to indentify https requests for Mongrel
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
  nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
  downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  DocumentRoot /home/usr/www/www.sub.domain.com/current/public/
  <Directory "/home/usr/www/www.sub.domain.com/current/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm *fairly* certain that you need the slash on the Redirect command:

```
  Redirect permanent / https://www.sub.domain.com/
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, but thanks.